# If Visual Studio’s Intellisense doesn’t suggest an option – does that mean it is not always supported?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have an `ObservableCollection` which I’m changing to an array using `string[] s = myObservableCollection.ToArray();`This works fine. I noticed, however, that VS does not offer that in its auto-complete. It only offers `ToArray<>` . So I wonder – does this mean it’s not supported in all cases or platforms etc. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it compiles, it is supported.

Intellisense is not perfect and relying on it too much is a mistake. As you have seen, a perfectly valid option didn't come up.

In this case, the method is probably the `IEnumerable<T>.ToArray()` extension method provided by LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Right, ObservableCollection<> doesn't have a ToArray() method.  You get the Linq extension method offered by IntelliSense, you no doubt have a *using System.Linq* directive at the top of the source code file.  Which does require that the machine you install this on has at least .NET version 3.5.  That's not hard to come by.

Comment: True. I’m `using System.Linq;` .